# What's the proper way to copy files while preserving folder structure in powershell?

Tags: powershell, copy

I can never seem to get this right.

I have an existing folder `c:\MyApps\Websites\MySite` that already has an existing website running in it. I've downloaded the latest bits which are located under `c:\temp\MySite\artifacts`.

when I try to run this

```
$source "c:\temp\MySite"
$destination "c:\MyApps\Websites\MySite"
copy-item $source $destination -recurse -force
```

if `c:\MyApps\Websites\MySite` already exists then it tries to put it in `c:\MyApps\Websites\MySite\artifacts`, but if it doesn't already exist it copies it properly. Not sure what's going on here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just use the `robocopy` command. It's **designed** for this kind of thing.

`robocopy $source $destination /E`

It's shipped with Windows 7, so it's an internal command, so it's still a 'Powershell' way, imho, but if you're wanting to use the copy command, then you are very close, but your current implementation grabs the `source` folder and puts it inside `target` (ie the result would be `C:\target\source\files`, not `C:\target\files`). When you want to make the inside of `target` look like the inside of `source`, you need to do:

`cp C:\source\* C:\target -r -fo`

Notice the `*`, this grabs the **contents** of the `source` folder. If you want `target` to be cleared first, just do `rm -r -fo C:\target\*` before the copy.

**Powershell doesn't handle long paths, so you will need to use robocopy anyway if you have a long filename or deep folders.**

Comment: This doesn't sync the folders does it? In other words if files exist in the target directory but not the source directory will it delete them?

Comment: @Micah To delete things in the destination that are NOT in source, you have to issue the `/PURGE` flag. Also, `/MIR` is equivalent to `/E /PURGE`. You can view more information by issuing `robocopy /?`

Comment: Holy sh*tballs Robocopy! Where have you been all my life. I'm upvoting the answer because it's awesome, but I still would like to know how to do it the powershell way..